# Fatal Exception when trying to write on phone memory: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

This is the full exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 79386366 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 75MB until OOM
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:133)
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
   at ch.usi.jacopofidacaro.umob.background.RecordStorageManager.store(RecordStorageManager.java:156)
   at ch.usi.jacopofidacaro.umob.recordCommuter.RecordCommuter.storeLocally(RecordCommuter.java:76)
   at ch.usi.jacopofidacaro.umob.background.BackgroundRecorder.recordGyroscope(BackgroundRecorder.java:591)
   at ch.usi.jacopofidacaro.umob.background.BackgroundRecorder$1.run(BackgroundRecorder.java:139)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And here is where it is occurred:

```
public void store(Record record, String recordId, Context ctx, String recordType) {

    Log.i(STORE, "store():");

    // convert the POJO to JSON
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(record);

    String filePath = recordType + "_records";
    File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), filePath);
    Log.i(STORE, "  target file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());


    Log.i(STORE, "  locally storing record: " + recordId);
    try {

        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(json);
        bw.close();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            text.append(line).append('\n');
        br.close();
        Log.i(STORE, "  record stored.");


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

In short, I am reading gyroscope sensor data and store them in a local file named gyroscope_records. Every hour, I am connecting to Firebase to upload the file and start writing to a new file for the next hour. It seems to me that if the sensor readings are too much and the file gets very big, then this exception happens. However, I have no idea how to handle it. How can I read/write big files (if that is the issue here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you're going to have to break up the file into smaller parts.  You've got a nearly 80MB file currently and it sounds like it could get even bigger.  Your issue is that you're trying to read that whole file into memory and you can't.

A few suggestions:

- Create many small files.  I don't know how big a `Record` is in this case but perhaps a new file every minute or something that holds a smaller number of Records.
- Use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) and store each record in a database.  Periodically have another thread read those records out, send them on, and delete them.
- Append to the large file only.  Do not read it into memory.

There are other possibilities but you simply can't keep it all in memory.

Comment: How can I append the file without reading it? Then, wouldn't it be a problem again when I want to upload it to Firebase? Thanks.

Comment: You're already doing it in the first part of your try block.  But then you try to re-read the file - I don't understand what that is doing but it is reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Ah I see. thanks for your help. Do you have any idea if uploading a big file to Firebase would cause a similar exception?

Comment: I'm not sure on the Firebase side I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I see no use in the StringBuilder "`text`", yet it is `text.append(...)` that causes the exception. So have you tried removing the variable together with the `while` loop?